# Angular.ts and Electron: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I install Electron on a new angular app and get this error by running electron.
I use TypeScript.
The error message:

> import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
> ^^^^^^
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

this error is shown also after I add "type": "module" to the package.json file.

when I try to use .mjs extension by replacing the main.ts file to main.mjs file and add the following to package.json file:

```
"jest": {
"preset": "ts-jest/presets/default-esm",
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "useESM": true
  }
},
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1"
}
```

}

I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "desktop-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron",
    "start:electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.33",
    "electron": "^15.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "path": ["./node_modules/path-browserify"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

[my files list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqNrO.png)

What can I do to fix it?
Please help!
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created a new file - main.js - regardless of the main.ts of the src folder and put the electron code here.
It was a mistake to link between them.
There's no conflict between JS and TS.